# weblogic.management.provider.EditSaveChangesFailedException:

Tags: java, linux, weblogic11g

I am getting above mention exception in Weblogic 11g. When I am updating/changing any configuration related setting except Data source in Weblogic console this error comes.

> weblogic.management.provider.EditSaveChangesFailedException:

For example I am trying to update mail session through weblogic console.my weblogic server in present in Linux system (at Cloud JCS).

Comment: I am not sure this is enough information to help you. Is there a stack trace? Do you have some code that causes this error?

Answer (score 0):

Undo all changes from the change center, Restart Admin Server, then try again

Must be some conflicting change which is not allowing to activate

Comment: Actually we have 3 managed domain , Two are working fine only one is giving below issue.we have done everything means we made that domain as its early state(when we create domain).but we got same error.